# How to set AvalonDock DockablePane to right in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I need to set AvalonDock DockablePane to right side of a WPF window, can you please help me to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ad:DockablePane>
            <ad:DockableContent DockableStyle="RightBorder">
                 ....
```