# avalonDock : how to align the tabs to the top right?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I am creating a DockingManager with avalonDock in my xaml file and i can't figure out a way to align the tabs it creats on the top right. They are always on the top left side.

like this :

[image]

I have seen : [How to set AvalonDock DockablePane to right in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940875/how-to-set-avalondock-dockablepane-to-right-in-wpf)
but I could not find "ResizingPanel" under "DockingManager"

Does anyone knows how to do it ?

here is a sample of my xaml :

```
<Grid>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager"  Margin="0,10,0,-10"
                               DocumentsSource="{Binding Files}"
                               Grid.Row="0" >
        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
            <panel:PanelTemplateSelector>
                <panel:PanelTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <view:Shooting/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </panel:PanelTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
            </panel:PanelTemplateSelector>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>


        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <panel:PanelStyleSelector>
                <panel:PanelStyleSelector.StartPageStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonControl:LayoutItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Model.StartPageTip}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </panel:PanelStyleSelector.StartPageStyle>
            </panel:PanelStyleSelector>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>

        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
            <panel:LayoutInitializer/>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>

    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say hi at the beginning  of the post, but it wouldn't allow me to edit it ... :(

Answer (score 2):

TabItems are hosted in a DocumentPaneTabPanel which its FlowDirection property has been set to LeftToRight in constructor,

i recommend do the following:

1. Copy the following in the form where the DockingManager is located:

   ```
   private void DockingManager_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var q = FindVisualChild<Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls.DocumentPaneTabPanel>(dockingManager);
       if (q != null)
       {
           q.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
           dockingManager.LayoutUpdated -= DockingManager_LayoutUpdated;
       }
   }
   public T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
       {
           DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
           if (child != null && child is T)
               return (T)child;
           else
           {
               T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
               if (childOfChild != null)
                   return childOfChild;
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. Copy the following in the form's Constructor after InitializeComponent:

   ```
     dockingManager.LayoutUpdated += DockingManager_LayoutUpdated;
   ```

Now , my CodeBehind looks like this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dockingManager.LayoutUpdated += DockingManager_LayoutUpdated;
    }
    private void DockingManager_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var q = FindVisualChild<Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls.DocumentPaneTabPanel>(dockingManager);
        if (q != null)
        {
            q.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            dockingManager.LayoutUpdated -= DockingManager_LayoutUpdated;
        }
    }
    public T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```